# Xcode 9 Compiler Hangs On File With No Warnings Or Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode9, swift4

**Background:**
Attempting to upgrade large 100k codebase from Swift 2.3 to Swift 4. Was making good progress, fixed ~1000 error. Then, after changing one of our DTO objects to use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` (because we had to), the compiler started hanging.

**Problem:**
When compiling the application will get to a certain file and just get stuck (even after 24 hours). It is not frozen just stuck compiling. I have tried temp removing the file but then it just gets stuck on another file and so on and so on.

**Research & Attempts**
I've read up on the compiler and how to turn on warnings and flags. I tried looking at `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` and `-Xfrontend Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking` but nothing comes up. When I look at the build transcript for the file its stuck on there is no info in the expanded transcript.

Do you know what else I can check? I suspect it has something to do with its inability to infer type given how many `Any` filled dictionaries we have but without getting better information I have no clue where to go from here.

Do you know how I can get info as to why it's getting stuck on this file and no warnings given?

Comment: I doubt that the Swift 4 migrator is able to migrate directly from Swift 2 to 4. The first sentence in [Pre-Migration Preparation](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4/) is *Make sure that the project that you intend to migrate builds successfully in Swift 3.2 mode*. That implies you should first update to Swift 3

Comment: I did a quick conversion to Swift 3 but I left the errors in. After it was converted, I then opened in Swift 4. After that I started fixing errors. As per your suggestion perhaps I should get it fully built in 3.2. I will look into this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To followup, it took several days, but by first converting to Swift 3.2 and then Swift 4 (commenting out most code to solve later) I was able to get it to compile in Xcode 9.